# Move in Text animation visible outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move in text from bottom of the div that is a red tile on hover , but when i hover the text is visible from outside the tile ,and moves in , what i want is for it to seem like it moved in from bottom of the tile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tile">
        <div class="front">
        </div>
        <div class="back"></div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}
.tile{
    background: red;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    z-index:-1;
}
.tile:HOVER {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    z-index:-1;
}

.back{
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tile").hover(function(){
            $(".front").hide().empty();
            $(".back")
            $(".back").show().append("<h3>Welcome</h3>" +
                "<p>This is th content being changed</p>");
            $(".back").animate({top:'-=100px',opacity:"1"},"slow");
    },function(){
        $(".back").animate( {top:"+=100px",opacity:"0"},"fast").hide().empty();
        $(".front").show().append("<h3>Hello<h3>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tile {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden; // add this line
  z-index: -1;
}
```

overflow: hidden;

> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. No scrollbars
>   are provided.

which means the text outside the range of `.tile` will be invisible.

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tile").hover(function() {
    $(".front").hide().empty();
    $(".back")
    $(".back").show().append("<h3>Welcome</h3>" +
      "<p>This is th content being changed</p>");
    $(".back").animate({
      top: '-=100px',
      opacity: "1"
    }, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $(".back").animate({
      top: "+=100px",
      opacity: "0"
    }, "fast").hide().empty();
    $(".front").show().append("<h3>Hello<h3>");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.tile {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tile:HOVER {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.back {
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile">
  <div class="front">
  </div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```